# Can I crossfade divs on click of a nav button using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation (*sort of navigation*) which have three buttons. My goal is that when I click a button on the navigation, the `div`s fade rather than there being a hard transition (which is what I've got going on currently). I want it to look like the images are crossfading when you click on different nav buttons.

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani:900');
  
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
  
  body{
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  a:visited, a:link, a:active{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 680px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #eee;
  }
  
  #images{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 180px;
    height: 560px;
  }

  #navigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .button{
    background: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="button"><a href="#one">01</a></div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#two">02</a></div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#three">03</a></div>
</div>
<div id="images">
  <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;"> 
    <a name="one">
    <div style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: none;" align="center"> 
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/crLo5L/outfit2.png" width="179">
    </div>
    </a>
    <a name="two">
    <div style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: none;" align="center"> 
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jT7CX0/outfit1.png" width="179">
    </div>
    </a>
    <a name="three">
    <div style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: none;" align="center"> 
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iNqMQL/outfit3.png" width="179">
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I really want to achieve this using only CSS. The website that I make my profiles on only permits JS for premium users, so I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @RonenCypis, Indeed, its working! take my ++ ;)

Comment: @Ashton, in order to achieve this behaviour you have to  dramatically change the structure of your HTML, and put every image as a descendant of its respective button. 
Check out my answer below with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given HTML structure in your question, i couldn't think of a way to achieve this. But with some structural changes, I managed to achieve the desired behaviour. 
Check it out:

(I've dumbed down your code just to prove a point, this works perfectly without any JS running...)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani:900');
  
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
  
  body{
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  #navigation{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  button {
    background: black;
    color:white;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
button:focus {outline:0;}
button:focus img {opacity: 1;}
img {position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;opacity:0;transition:opacity 800ms;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navigation">
  <button>01<img src="https://image.ibb.co/crLo5L/outfit2.png" width="179"></button>
  <button>02<img src="https://image.ibb.co/jT7CX0/outfit1.png" width="179"></button>
  <button>03<img src="https://image.ibb.co/iNqMQL/outfit3.png" width="179"></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice one :) I recommand use `:focus{outline: 0;}` to hide the outline(the skyblue that defined as default in browser)

Comment: @DudeCoder that the behavior of `focus`

Comment: @RonenCypis Thank you so much! This actually worked! I did tweak it just a tad (but not structurally), to make sure that at least one image is showing (I didn't want a blank space by default). I added a <button style="background: white; opacity: 1;"> so the first image is displayed at default, and <button style="background white;"> to the last two. They still crossfade beautifully. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a vertical scroll effect by setting `translateY`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Biryani:900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
body {
  background: #fff;
}

a:visited,
a:link,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 680px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #eee;
}

#images {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 180px;
  height: 560px;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  background: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.section {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0);
  transform: translateZ( 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

a[id="one"]:target~#images div.section {
  transform: translateY( 0px);
}

a[id="two"]:target~#images div.section {
  transform: translateY( -560px);
}

a[id="three"]:target~#images div.section {
  transform: translateY( -1120px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <a id="one"></a>
  <a id="two"></a>
  <a id="three"></a>
  <div id="navigation">
    <div class="button"><a href="#one">01</a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#two">02</a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#three">03</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="images">
    <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
      <a name="one">
        <div id="one" class="section" style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: none;" align="center">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/crLo5L/outfit2.png" width="179">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a name="two">
        <div id="two" class="section" style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: none;" align="center">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jT7CX0/outfit1.png" width="179">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a name="three">
        <div id="three" class="section" style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: none;" align="center">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iNqMQL/outfit3.png" width="179">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfection

Comment: @DudeCoder, While this effect is very nice, it doesn't really answer the question...